# Can Printed Circuit Boards or other electronic devices (Integrated Circuits, transistors) be damaged by water if the electricity is turned off?

Tags: power, transistors, pcb, water, waterproof

Is it possible that electric or electronic devices be damaged by exposure to water if the current is turned off during their exposure to water and the electricity is switched back on only after the water is completely dried off ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should no be any damage occurring to the PCB or integrated circuit if it is completely dried off.  One possible error is that the PCB or integrated circuit may be powered back on too early and not everything is completely dried.  But it can take days/week for the integrated circuit to completely dry off.

Comment: Mineral content in the water could stick around after the water has evaporated and cause or contribute to short circuits.

Comment: You don't think energy stored in capacitors is anything to worry about?

Comment: There are a lot of components like sensors that will be damaged when they get wet. Certain underfills do not like water too, also there are many different metals around so that there is always a chance that some kind of battery forms that can corrode things, especially under BGA parts this is hart to spot

Comment: @Bort If the device is powered off, most capacitors in typical devices will be discharged.